# How to inject docker environment variable inside Spring boot application

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, spring-boot, environment-variables

I am using dockerized images to run on AWS ECS containers.

dockerfile :

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-Dspring.profiles.active=${profile}","-jar","/app.jar"]`
```

Is it possible for me to fetch this variable inside my spring boot class?

Want to use this to set profiles inside my spring boot application.

Comment: Please post your Dockerfile, the command-line you are running the container with, spring-boot version, etc. There's too little information here. Some reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yes, you can, any problem?

Comment: Any reference or examples as how to?

Comment: Please look at this post if it helps 
http://www.littlebigextra.com/use-spring-profiles-docker-containers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Enviroment Variables within Dockerfile after "FROM" line, like this:

```
ENV JAVA_BASE="/opt/java"
```

For each variables you need to add a new "ENV" line.

Comment: and how do I use this JAVA_BASE variable inside my spring boot application class?